# Subscribe to Angular Material Mat-Drawer events .. Ex: openedChange

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular5, angular6

I'm using mat-drawer and I want to be notified in the associated Component, when the mat-drawer is opened and close to add some logic at that moment;

The html has the follosing structure :

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container"  autosize>
<mat-drawer #drawer class="custom-sidenav" mode="side">
    <div>
  <button routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active"
   style="margin-top: 50px" mat-button class="small" (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" >
    <mat-icon style="color: red">home</mat-icon>
  <b style="margin-left: 20px">Home</b>
  </button>
</div>
  <div>
  <button routerLink="/transactions" routerLinkActive="active" style="margin-top: 20px" mat-button class="small" (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" >
    <mat-icon style="color:gray">trending_flat</mat-icon>
  <b matBadge="{{totalTransactions}}" matBadgeColor="red" matBadgeOverlap="false" style="margin-left: 20px">Transactions</b>
  </button>
</div>
  <div *ngIf="isAdmin">
        <button routerLink="/fetch-data" routerLinkActive="active" style="margin-top: 20px" mat-button class="small" (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" >
            <mat-icon  matBadge="{{totalCertificates}}" matBadgePosition="before" matBadgeColor="accent"  style="color:gray">description</mat-icon>
          <b style="margin-left: 20px">Certificates</b>
          </button>
  </div>
  <div>
        <button (click)="navigateToMyCertificates()"  routerLinkActive="active" style="margin-top: 20px" mat-button class="small" (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" >
            <mat-icon  matBadge="{{myCertificates}}" matBadgePosition="before" matBadgeColor="accent"  style="color:gray">description</mat-icon>
          <b style="margin-left: 20px">My Certificates</b>
          </button>
  </div>
  <div>
        <button routerLink="/certificate-validator" routerLinkActive="active" style="margin-top: 20px" mat-button class="small" (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" >
            <mat-icon  style="color:black">check</mat-icon>
          <b style="margin-left: 20px">Validate Certificate</b>
          </button>
  </div>
</mat-drawer>
```

and this is the associated Component class :

```
export class HomeLayoutComponent {
..etc
```

}

What is the required code that needs to be added in the mat-drawer and in the component to realize a correct binding that will fire the "openedChange" event in the Component class

Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it.  You can either do

```
<mat-drawer #drawer (openedChange)="onOpenedChange($event)"></mat-drawer>
```

In your component you would then have a method

```
onOpenedChange(e: boolean)
```

Or you can do it using a view child in the component

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('drawer') drawer: MatDrawer;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.drawer.openedChange.subscribe((o: boolean) => { console.log(`IsOpen: ${o}`) });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I suppose the recommended version is the 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to [the official website of angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api). They have a very nice doc of that.

Above answer is perfect.
Just adding some more info.

There are many other events like: openedStart, closedStart, onPositionChanged ... etc